# mdapi convert command fails when source has lightning web component bundle

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

With the latest CLI (sfdx-cli/6.52.2-c6cdc99881 (darwin-x64) node-v8.9.4) i have observed that the mdapi:source convert fails when the package has the lwc bundle .

The salesforcedx plugin version is ***salesforcedx 45.1.2***

Steps to reproduce

1. Create an unmanaged package in Developer Edition org with lwc bundle and retrieve src by package name  or clone the git repo here https://github.com/msrivastav13/mdapi-convert-lwc-bug.git
2. Source convert it using below

   *sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r ./mdapiout -d force-app*

The error in the console is as below

An error was encountered processing path: /Users/mohith/Desktop/Projects/DemoApplication/mdapio
ut/src/lwc//.html.

Here is the complete log for more info.

https://textuploader.com/1a8hn

Anybody else facing this or it's just me ?

Comment: I am getting the exact same error with the exact same version of Salesforce DX

Comment: no, you're not the only one. I've got the exact same error too. anyone hears from Salesforce on this ?

Comment: They working on the fix .No updates yet .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed by salesforce CLI team .

[image]

Its also good to bookmark the CLI release notes [url](https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/releasenotes.html).